# codeigniter form_validation is not working...(for me)

Tags: php, validation, forms, codeigniter

Ok, I'm trying to validate a form in codeigniter

as a first step I want to make all fields in my form required to make an entry...
but I can't make it work

here is the code:

myBlog.php

```
    <?php

    class MyBlog extends Controller{


       function MyBlog(){
           parent::Controller();
           $this->load->helper('url'); //here we load a url class that we use later
           $this->load->helper('form');// here we load form class


           $this->load->scaffolding('entries');  //scaffolfing is a feature that lets you add or remove elements from the database



            $this->load->library('form_validation');//load validation class used to validate our forms...
       }

      function index(){

          $data['title'] = "My Blog Title"; //the title of my blog
          $data['query'] = $this->db->get('entries'); //here we make a small query to entries table


          $this->load->view('myBlog_view', $data); ///load all data variables on myBlog_view.php
         //this is also for the form validation


            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('author', 'Author', 'required');





          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                //$this->load->view('myBlog_view');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('formSuccess_view');
            }

 }






     function myBlog_insert(){

           $this->db->insert('entries', $_POST);

           redirect('myBlog/');
           }


    } 

    ?>
```

also myBlog_view.php file:

```
<html>
<head>

<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>




<?php foreach($query->result() as $row): ?>
 <div class='curvebox'>
<h3><?=$row->title?></h3>


<p class="bodyText"><?=$row->body?></p>
<div class="author"><?="by: ".$row->author." on ".date("D d M Y h:i:s A", strtotime($row->date_time))?></div>
<p class="comments"><?=anchor('myBlog/comments/'.$row->id, 'Comments');?></p>
</div>


<?php endforeach; ?>



<div class="theForm">

<?php echo $this->form_validation->error_string; ?>

<?=form_open('myBlog/myBlog_insert');?>


<label for="title">Title:</label>

<input type='text' name="title" size="40" id="title" />
<p>
<label for="body">Body:</label>
<textarea name="body" rows = "10" cols="60" id="body"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<label for="author">Author:</label>
<input type="text" name="author" size="40" id="author"/>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit New Post"/></p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

everything works fine except the fact that it would accept entries with by a form half-filled

sorry for the long code....
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not relevant to your question but you can call multiple helpers in one call like so: `$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));`

Comment: I suggest autoloading those helpers(in the autoload.php file) so you can use it everywhere without calling it

Comment: also, it's good practice to use <?php echo ?> not <?= because some servers don't support it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have your form post to itself. Right now it's skipping the validation.

All of your validation functions are in the index method.
Change this line in myBlog_view.php:

`<?=form_open('myBlog/myBlog_insert');?>`

to:

`<?=form_open('myBlog');?>`

And then you'll need to call the insert method after the validation, so in your controller, before this line: `$this->load->view('formSuccess_view');`

you'll need to add in this:

`$this->myBlog_insert();`

See if that works.

Comment: Can you not use $this->form_validation->run() if the form does not post to itself?